# Adding command line options to CMake

Tags: command-line, cmake

I'm building a large library using CMake, and I would like users to be able to selectively enable/disable certain parts of my build process.

How can I add command-line options to my CMake build, e.g. so that users may type something like `cmake --build-partone --nobuild-parttwo --dothis=true --dothat=false ..`?

Apparently the OPTION keyword will create variables that can be set from the CMake GUI, but I can't figure out how to do this from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your question as it answered my question with regards to the purpose of cmake option. So, i see now it is for GUI

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Yeah, you should use the `option` command. You can set options from the command line this way:

```
//CMakeLists.txt
option(MyOption "MyOption" OFF)

//Command line
cmake -DMyOption=ON MyProjectFolder
```

Note that `-DMyOption` must come before the path.

Comment: ... and `cmake MyProjectFolder -DMyOption` does not turn the option on (or off)

Comment: put -DMyOption before MyProjectFolder and take a try?

Comment: Use `-DMyOption=ON` or `-DMyOption=OFF` to turn on or off.

Comment: I just noticed as I was trying to build a third party module that items set with "set(NAME blahblah)" in CMakeLists.txt are overridable with -DNAME=overridingValue  on the cmake command line,

Answer (score 17):

Just a little correction:

If you have other variables to pass, it is recommended to indicate the type of these:

```
//CMakeLists.txt
option(MyOption "MyOption" OFF)

//Command line
cmake -DMyOption:BOOL=ON -D... MyProjectFolder
```

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Should the `-D...` must lie behind `MyProjectFolder`? If it's the case, why?