# How to set a CMake option() at command line

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I created a CMakeLists.txt that contains the following

```
project(P4V)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

option(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build the static library" ON)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" ON)
option(BUILD_TESTS "Build test programs" OFF)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

add_subdirectory(src)
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif(BUILD_TESTS)
```

By default BUILD_TESTS is OFF, how can I turn it ON without CMake GUI, but with cmake command itself?
I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
cmake .. -G %1 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=ON
```

Comment: List your flags before `..` argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/cmake-adding-command-line-options

Comment: As the answer to the 5998186 points out it is 'cmake MyProjectFolder -DMyOption=ON'

Comment: Have you removed CMakeCache.txt before cmake again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding command line options to CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/adding-command-line-options-to-cmake)

Comment: I wish this was answered on https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html.

Comment: @Denilson Amorim What's the `%1` in your command line?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Delete the CMakeCache.txt file and try this:

```
cmake -G %1 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=ON ..
```

You have to enter all your command-line definitions before including the path.

Comment: How to specifically specify OFF? I just can't seem to get the CUDA option turned off.

Comment: @Ébe-isaac If you want to explicitly turn an option OFF just use `-DOPTION=OFF`.

Comment: It seems you no longer have to pass the options before the path: `cmake .. -G <whatever> -DOPTION=ON` works fine for me with CMake 3.16.2.

Comment: To fix an option to use a new default value, instead of the one from the original CMake directory setup before the default was changed - for me it was enough to delete `CMakeCache.txt` and run `ninja` _et al._ again. I didn't have to run `cmake` again. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

this works for me:

```
cmake -D DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON DBUILD_TESTS=ON ..
```

Answer (score 10):

An additional option is to go to your build folder and use the command `ccmake .`

This is like the GUI but terminal based. This obviously won't help with an installation script but at least it can be run without a UI.

The one warning I have is it won't let you generate sometimes when you have warnings. if that is the case, exit the interface and call `cmake .`

Comment: The OP specifically asks for "no GUI".