# Appending CXX_FLAGS in cmake invocation

Tags: c++, c++11, build, cmake

I am wondering if it is possible to append to inferred variables when calling `cmake`. Due either the compiler or the app supplied `CMakeLists.txt` C++11 support isn't detected by `cmake` even though it is supported and the application requires it. If I do:

```
cmake-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++11' ../source_dir
```

The flags get overwritten and I wouldn't like to lose the inferred flags. I could manually run without overwriting and just copy the flags and append c++11 but I think there must be a better solution.

I have found a number of posts on adding c++11 support to `CMakeLists.txt` but not in `cmake` call, so I am wondering if this is possible at all. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. First, create a variable called `MY_FLAGS` in the command line with the flags you want.

```
cmake -DMY_FLAGS='-std=c++11' ../source_dir
```

Then, in your `CMakeLists.txt`, do the following:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MY_FLAGS}")
```

This will effectively amend your flags to the flags that CMake generates. However, if you want to set the C++ standard to C++11, you can just do the following without directly dealing with flags:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON ../source_dir
```

On a side note, make sure that the `../source_dir` is *after* the CMake options, since otherwise `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` would not work. ([Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435516/how-to-set-a-cmake-option-at-command-line))

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this, when building a dependency for one of the applications I work to.
There are 2 CMake variables that you can make use of, namely:

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug/Release
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_[DEBUG/RELEASE]
```

When specifying a build type, cmake will add to the compiler flags the flags that are specified in that second variable. So for me, using:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-fPIC
```

did the thing.

In your case, you can try the following approaches:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-std=c++11
or
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-std=c++11
```

Of course, this will work if the variables are not overwritten in the script. Try both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

Or via command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
```

That being said, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not overridden by cmake, so your CMakeLists.txt must be doing it somewhere. 
The polite way of setting the flags from within a script is to *append* to the variable, that is:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} stuff")
```

Comment: So I was looking for a way to do it without changing anything in the original CMakeLists.txt. I thought -D overwrites the variable and I can clearly see it in the case of that library. Is this something I need to pick up with the devlopers?

Comment: `-D` 'predefines' the variable. Probably the developers are overwriting whatever you pass via command line.