# CMake exclude submodule targets

Tags: cmake, target, glfw

I import glfw as submodule in my project, following the pattern described [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/projects/submodule.html)

```
find_package(Git QUIET)

if(GIT_FOUND AND EXISTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    # Update submodules as needed
    option(GIT_SUBMODULE "Check submodules during build" ON)
    if(GIT_SUBMODULE)
        message(STATUS "Submodule update")
        execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} submodule update --init --recursive
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
            RESULT_VARIABLE GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT)
        if(NOT GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT EQUAL "0")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "git submodule update --init failed with ${GIT_SUBMOD_RESULT}, please checkout submodules")
        endif()
    endif()
endif()

## Check for GLFW
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw/CMakeLists.txt")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The submodules were not downloaded! GIT_SUBMODULE was turned off or failed. Please update submodules and try again.")
else()
    add_subdirectory(glfw EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

As you can notice, I'm including the project with `add_subdirectory()`. This effectively adds the glfw target and I can link it with mine, but it also includes all the glfw targets (docs, examples, ...).

Surely, I'm including the project in the wrong way, I don't know.

Is there any way to include from submodule and exclude the other targets?

Apparently `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435516/how-to-set-a-cmake-option-at-command-line) the options defined in the GLFW `CMakeLists.txt` file from the command line. This will turn off the extra builds:

```
cmake -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF ..
```

If you want to override the default GLFW options by editing your top-level CMake file instead, you can do as @Cinder Biscuits suggested, but place the `set()` commands **before** the `add_subdirectory()` call:

```
## Check for GLFW
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw/CMakeLists.txt")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The submodules were not downloaded! GIT_SUBMODULE was turned off or failed. Please update submodules and try again.")
else()
    set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without examples")
    set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without tests")
    set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without docs")
    add_subdirectory(glfw EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the looks of it](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L22), you just need to tell CMake not to build those by setting those options in the CACHE. add this to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without examples")
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without tests")
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build GLFW without docs")
```

You need to specify the variable type and a description so CMake knows how to display this entry in the GUI.

Comment: I added the lines right after `add_subdirectory(glfw EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)`, and didn't work, still appears in project builds and cmake reserve the name "docs" for that target

Comment: You have to place them before `add_subdirectory()`, otherwise they won't be read until after the subdirectory has been processed.