# Compiler not finding jpeg and png libraries

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, g++, jpeg

I have downloaded and installed this C++ package for plotting and visulisation https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus. I have sussessfully linked to it in my CMake file and have no linking errors when including `#include <matplot/matplot.h>`. However, whenever I use any functions from the library matplot.h I get the following error at compilation.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::_cimg_jpeg_error_exit(jpeg_common_struct*)':
common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE21_cimg_jpeg_error_exitEP18jpeg_common_struct[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE21_cimg_jpeg_error_exitEP18jpeg_common_struct]+0x1e): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::_save_jpeg(_IO_FILE*, char const*, unsigned int) const':
common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x12b): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x152): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x16d): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x198): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x1b2): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x1c6): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x2cf): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x2ed): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_save_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x302): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::_save_png(_IO_FILE*, char const*, unsigned int) const':
common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x2f4): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x309): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x32b): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x34f): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x409): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x474): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x485): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0xc36): undefined reference to `png_write_image'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0xc43): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0xc50): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_save_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcj]+0x1830): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::save_cimg(char const*, bool) const':
common.cpp:(.text._ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9save_cimgEPKcb[_ZNK12cimg_library4CImgIhE9save_cimgEPKcb]+0x3bb): undefined reference to `compress'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::_load_png(_IO_FILE*, char const*, unsigned int*)':
common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x88): undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0xa2): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0xb7): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0xcd): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0xef): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x14a): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x1c9): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x1d7): undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x1e4): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x20e): undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x252): undefined reference to `png_get_valid'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x280): undefined reference to `png_set_filler'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x28d): undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x2c2): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x369): undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x389): undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x3a9): undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS_to_alpha'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x41f): undefined reference to `png_read_image'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x42c): undefined reference to `png_read_end'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x461): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x4f1): undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x683): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x84a): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE9_load_pngEP8_IO_FILEPKcPj]+0x9d3): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImgList<unsigned char>::_load_cimg(_IO_FILE*, char const*)':
common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x404): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x70c): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x93b): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0xce5): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x10f7): undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o):common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library8CImgListIhE10_load_cimgEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x1506): more undefined references to `uncompress' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(common.cpp.o): in function `cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char>::_load_jpeg(_IO_FILE*, char const*)':
common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x67): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0xb3): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0xc5): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0xd2): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0xda): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x1f8): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x278): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/usr/bin/ld: common.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc[_ZN12cimg_library4CImgIhE10_load_jpegEP8_IO_FILEPKc]+0x284): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(network.cpp.o): in function `matplot::network::process_force_layout()':
network.cpp:(.text+0x304e): undefined reference to `nodesoup::size_radiuses(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > > > const&, double, double)'
/usr/bin/ld: network.cpp:(.text+0x312a): undefined reference to `nodesoup::fruchterman_reingold(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > > > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, double, std::function<void (std::vector<nodesoup::Point2D, std::allocator<nodesoup::Point2D> > const&, int)>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmatplot.a(network.cpp.o): in function `matplot::network::process_kawai_layout()':
network.cpp:(.text+0x3842): undefined reference to `nodesoup::size_radiuses(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > > > const&, double, double)'
/usr/bin/ld: network.cpp:(.text+0x390c): undefined reference to `nodesoup::kamada_kawai(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned long> > > > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, double, double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make:84: example] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

The errors are plenty, but they are all of the form `undefined reference to png_...` or `undefined reference to jpeg_...` except for those that are `undefined reference to 'uncompress'`. It seems as though CMake is not finding png and jpeg. I definitely do have libjpeg and libpng installed. Why are these errors ocurring? Do I need to add lines to my CMakeLists.txt to find jpeg and png? I am running Ubuntu 20.04, g++ 9.3.0, and cmake 3.16.3.

Here is a very simple example that prodces the error. This is the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "c++")

find_package(Matplot++)
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC matplot)
```

Here is an example c++ code (pulled directly from the examples on the linked site).

```
#include <cmath>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>

int main() {
    using namespace matplot;

    std::vector<double> x = linspace(0, 10, 150);
    std::vector<double> y = transform(x, [](auto x) { return cos(5 * x); });
    plot(x, y)->color({0, 0.7, 0.9});
    title("2-D Line Plot");
    xlabel("x");
    ylabel("cos(5x)");

    show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @drescherjm I can do that, give me a minute.

Comment: As for the downvote and suggestion to close, I assume that was you @S.M., while that linked question is helpful, it is far more general than this and is not easily applicable. My question is a lot more specific.

Comment: @drescherjm, there is a simple example. Is there any more detail I should include?

Comment: You have improved the question. I don't know matplot but see that its a static library with several dependencies. I will look at the project to see if there is an easy fix.

Comment: It seems like this is a problem being worked on by the developers: [https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus/commit/2a9b87d891fdb899959a8db92b8724a3bae1b247](https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus/commit/2a9b87d891fdb899959a8db92b8724a3bae1b247)

Comment: My advice is to reconfigure matplot with CMake and enable the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option and rebuild matplot as a shared library. I think that would work around this problem. That is unless you have not updated from the source within the last 4 days. The fix for the static library linking problem I posted in the last comment was 4 days ago.

Comment: I downloaded and installed today. So, after editing the CMakeList.txt in the matplotplusplus directory to enable `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`, would I have to reinstall matplot?

Comment: You would not have to edit the file. You would use cmake-gui or cmake to set the option at the CMake configure stage Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435516/how-to-set-a-cmake-option-at-command-line/48503241](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435516/how-to-set-a-cmake-option-at-command-line/48503241)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221156/discussion-between-drescherjm-and-epiliam).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with Windows MinGW). Thanks to @drescherjm hint (add the option `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`), these are the steps I used to solve the problem:

```sh
git clone http://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus
cd matplotplusplus/
mkdir compil-release && cd compil-release 
rm CMakeCache.txt # if already exists
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${YOUR_LIB_PATH}/matplot1.0.1" 
make -j4 && make install
```

Then, and I guess that is a bug, I had to manually copy the .dll to the install path

```sh
cp source/matplot/libmatplot.dll ${YOUR_LIB_PATH}/matplot1.0.1/lib/
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I ended up just keeping the matplotplusplus folder as a subdirectory and it worked fine, but I will give that a go as an install would be better, thanks.