# File selection with conan and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a package with 2 variants with the following directory structure

```
pkg
   pkg_main.h
   CMakeLists.txt
   var1
      pkg_main.cpp
   var2
      pkg_main.cpp
conanfile.py
```

With [conan](https://conan.io/), I'm trying to define an option `fileSelection` with possible values `var1` and `var2`.
With cmake, I'm trying to do the selection as following: if `fileSelection` is set to `var1`, then `var1/pkg_main.cpp` shall be called, otherwise `var2/pkg_main.cpp`.
So far, I've defined the option `fileSelection` in `conanfile.py`

```
class PkgConan(ConanFile):
   name = "pkg"
   ...
   options = {"fileSelection : ['var1', 'var2']"}
   default_options = "fileSelection=var1"
   generators = "cmake"

   def build(self): 
      cmake = CMake(self)
      cmake.configure(source_folder="pkg")
      cmake.build()

   def package(self):
       self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="pkg")
       self.copy("*pkg.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
       self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
       self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
       self.copy("*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
       self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

   def package_info(self):
       self.cpp_info.libs = ["pkg"]
```

Now I'm struggling to update the `CMakeLists.txt` file to do the selection according to the value of `fileSelection`. Something like this:
[**here's the logic, not the runnable code**]

```
if("${fileSelection}" STREQUAL "var1") 
   add_library(pkg var1/pkg_main.cpp)
else
   add_library(pkg var2/pkg_main.cpp)
endif
```

**??** How do I pass the `fileSelection` option to cmake; where and how do I implement the switch between `var1` and `var2` (am I going in the right direction by trying to define the switch in CMakeLists.txt)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding command line options to CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/adding-command-line-options-to-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables to cmake command line invocation driven by the cmake helper. Something like:

```
options = {"fileSelection": ["var1", "var2"]}
...

def build(self): 
   cmake = CMake(self)
   cmake.definitions["fileSelection"] = self.options.fileSelection
   cmake.configure(source_folder="pkg")
   cmake.build()
```

That assumes that you have the CMakeLists.txt logic you describe.