# Using libwebsockets with LWS_ROLE_WS

Tags: c, cmake, libwebsockets

I compiled `libwebsockets` using:

```
cmake
make all
sudo make install
ldconfig
```

I'm trying to compile an example, but CMake gives the error that `lws` must have been configured with `LWS_ROLE_WS`. I cannot work out how to 'create' `lws` with that option.

I'm quite happy with makefiles, but I know little about CMake, and here the configuration appears to be very complicated. The build instructions include some options, but nothing relating to this.

Basically, I don't even understand where I should be looking; is it necessary to be fluent in CMake to use `libwebsockets`?

Comment: When configure the project with `cmake`, you may pass additional options with `-D<option-name>=ON/OFF`. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/adding-command-line-options-to-cmake) for examples.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Thanks. I recompiled / installed starting from cmake -DLWS_ROLE_WS but it changed nothing. I note that the test-client binary in the lws make all is being buil; it may that this is a local cmake error.

Comment: "I recompiled / installed starting from cmake -DLWS_ROLE_WS" - You mean `-DLWS_ROLE_WS=ON`, don't you? Please, add **exact error message** (with surrounding log lines) into the question post.

Comment: I used -DLWS_ROLE_WS=1, so I just re ran that with 'ON' to be sure. I noticed that cmake is apparently listing all the options, ON or OFF, and LWS_ROLE_WS is not among them. It also said for more help do cmake -LH. So I did. In the output I did see the entry: LWS_ROLE_WS:BOOL=ON which I assume it means this option should be on by default.

Comment: I just tried compiling using my own simple makefile and its fine, I think there is probably some sort of error in the cmake configuration of the example app; but as it happens I don't appear to need it, it compiles fine without!

Comment: "I assume it means this option should be on by default." - Hm, yes, ON is a [default value](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L27) for this option. Again, please, add **exact error message** to the question post, with surround info. With current information it is unclear what is going on.