# How to set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE option?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install opencv with the non-free features enabled. All the documentation I find says to "build it with cmake with the OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE option enabled."

I have no idea what that means. I barely understand cmake at all. I've been following [these instructions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). They seem pretty clear. However, I don't understand where in the process I'm supposed to enable that option. Is that option set in some configuration file? Is it a command line option? I'm afraid I just don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: "Is it a command line option?" - Most likely, yes. Have you tried that? See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/adding-command-line-options-to-cmake) about passing options to `cmake` via command line.

Comment: It means that you have to pass `-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON` in cmake. Take a look at [these](https://gist.github.com/underscoreanuj/0a29cecf7585c6304f07da39edbc419d) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As @[RJ Adriaansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11380795/rj-adriaansen) stated, you must rebuild the opencv lib with the cmake option -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON. Here is the installation process (please see the first cmake command/configuration which sets the nonfree boolean).

```
# Install minimal prerequisites (Ubuntu 18.04 as reference)
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y cmake g++ wget unzip

# Download and unpack sources
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.x.zip
unzip opencv.zip
unzip opencv_contrib.zip

# Create build directory and switch into it
mkdir -p build && cd build

# Configure
cmake -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-4.x/modules ../opencv-4.x

# Build 
cmake --build .
sudo make install
```

Also, check out this post:
https://answers.opencv.org/question/201938/how-can-i-set-opencv_enable_nonfree-cmake-option-and-rebuild-the-library-in-function-create/