# Can NOT find defined MACRO in cmake-3.16

Tags: cmake, build, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have following statement in my main CMakefile.txt:

```
add_definitions( -DAPP_ROLE_IS_QT )
```

In another CMakefile.txt that sits in a sub-dir, I need to check whether "`APP_ROLE_IS_QT`" has been defined or not, and do things accordingly:

```
if( DEFINED APP_ROLE_IS_QT )
    message( STATUS "It exitsts." )
    # do something ...
else()
    message( STATUS "It doesn't!!" )
    # do something else...
endif()
```

But it does **NOT** work, I always get "It doesn't!!";

CMAKE VERSION 3.16

Comment: So, what exactly do you want: define a **compiler macro** (with `add_definition`) or declare a **CMake variable** which you can check after (with `if(DEFINED)`)?

Comment: Sorry, my English is poor. I want define a macro so that I can use it in C++ source, and at same time, I need check whether it exists in cmake source and do right things.

Comment: Just define a **variable** `APP_ROLE_IS_QT` using `set` command. Using `if` in the main `CMakeLists.txt`, you could **conditionally** execute `add_definitions( -DAPP_ROLE_IS_QT )` in it. Using similar `if` in the sub-dir `CMakefile.txt`, you could conditionally execute `message`. If you want a user of your project to be able to set (or not set) the variable, then see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998186/adding-command-line-options-to-cmake

Comment: thank you, I have used your solution i.e. option()